# Linking c++ and c#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to link the C++ defined libraries , so that they be used in C#.
I have an `CString PastUsed` that holds a variable in C++, which I'm trying to
access in C#.

In C++, I stored the value of the variable `PastUsed` in the '.odl' file as
`BSTR PastUsed`.  I'm using `DISP_PROPERTY_EX` as a dispatch map.

```
DISP_PROPERTY_EX(Cpctr, "PastUsed", GetPastUsed, SetPastUsed, VT_BSTR).
```

I return the value of the String variable  from `GetPastUsed`.
But, I donot think this value is being saved in `PastUsed` (as defined in
.odl). This I'm assuming is happening because when I try to access this
variable (`PastUsed` from .odl) in C#, I get a com exception.

The code I have in c#  to retrieve the C++ defined variable is:

```
private void GetPastUsedDes_Click(Object eventSender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
{
    if (CheckInvalidButtonClick())
    { 
        return;
    } 
    PrintLine("Dumping past Used"); 
    AxPBSPRINTLib.AxPBSprint sPrint = mPBSPrintCtrl; 
    String str = mPBSPrintCtrl.PastUsed;
    String str = Print.PastUsed;
}
```

The `PastUsed` (here above one in c#) is the same string which is supposed to
be containing the variable held in `Pastused` of c++ (as described in my first
post). As soon as it hits the breakpoint of String str in c#, I get the
exception:

```
Print.PastUsed = 'Print.PastUsed' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like COM code to me.

You'd use COM interop (by referencing the typelibrary and using the generated interop classes for the COM interfaces).

See

- [COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [COM Interop Gets Much Better in C# 4.0](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42590)

Comment: Along side I also realized that the "PastUsed" defined in .odl along with the "GetPastUsed" and "SetPastUsed" also needs to be automated in MFC. Is there a way to automate on the existing MFC??

Comment: @user1515739 Please, I honestly don't know what you mean by 'automated in MFC'. I presume you need to consume the same COM interface from MFC. Yes, `CComPtr` is the way to do that. I think you need to post a small sample, just the interface in idl/odl and a minimal implementation in C++. We can't see enough to say anything more

Comment: within the '.odl' file I have added the :
        [id(41)] BSTR PastUsed;
the dispatch map associated with it is:
         DISP_PROPERTY_EX(CPBSprintCtrl,"PastUsed", GetPastUsed, SetPastUsed, VT_BSTR).
The definitions for get, set are:
        void CPBSprintCtrl::SetPastUsed(BSTR nNewValue) 
        {
        RefreshControl();
        }
        BSTR  CPBSprintCtrl::GetPastUsed() 
        {
        return m_pastUsed.AllocSysString();
        }

What needs to be done for this "PastUsed" to be used across the platform?? (in  C# to be used in COM library)?

Comment: @user1515739 erm... see [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529379/linking-c-and-c-sharp/11529468#comment15246752_11529468)? Also, this doesn't make a minimal example, see [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762)